# graph theory: how to convert a partial list of connections into an entire graph.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a set partially connected numbers, how do I find all numbers that are connected together either directly or through other numbers. For example:

```
 1     1
19     7
10     4
 4    19
22    25
13    22
 7    10
25    16
16    13
 2     3
20     9
11     6
 5    21
23    27
14    24
 8    12
26    18
17    15
 3     2
21     8
12     5
 6    20
24    26
15    23
 9    11
27    17
18    14
```

19 and 7 are connected and 7 and 10 are connected; therefore 19 and 10 are connected. What is a away (fast or elegant would be nice) in which all connections can be found and labeled according to the row that a number in the connection first appears? For example, the connection 19,7,10, and 4 would be labeled connection #2 because the first occurrence of any of 19,7,10,4 is row 2.

Answer (score 1):

So your pairs of numbers can represent edges in some graph. The 'connections' that you describe could be paths in the graph, except that it seems like the order you visit the edges in the path matters.

For example, if your example represents a directed graph, then there are a number of disconnected components that are cycles like: (19 -> 7 -> 10 -> 4 -> 19). I think you are saying that this should be labelled '2', right?

Perhaps the easiest way would be to make a graph where the vertices are labelled by the row. Then you would just find the connected components and label these by the lowest number in the component. Some difficulties might be that you seem to have loops (1 -> 1) and two-vertex cycles (2 -> 3 -> 2), which would make your graph non-simple.